# Content Security Policy issues on Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am having trouble getting my application to behave correctly on Google AppEngine. I have a Flask app that has its Content Security Policy (CSP) managed by [flask-talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman)

I am getting API calls blocked to http://my-project.appspot.com/api/foo because they violate "connect-src" policy. Requests to this URL are of type `xhr`. Actual message below:

```
Refused to connect to 'http://review-dot-my-project.appspot.com/api/foo' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' *.appspot.com".
```

In production, my URL is https://my-project.appspot.com

For review apps, my URL is http://review-dot-my-project.appspot.com

The http protocol is used in my review apps, in production it is https.

The relevant part of my CSP is as follows:

```
...
Talisman(app, content_security_policy={
        'default-src': ["'self'", "*.google.com"],
        ...
        'connect-src': ["'self'", "*.appspot.com"]
    })
```

I have tried many iterations of the `connect-src` portion of my CSP

```
'connect-src': ["'self'", "*://*.appspot.com"]

'connect-src': ["'self'", "*://*my-project.appspot.com"]

'connect-src': ["'self'", "*.appspot.com"]

'connect-src': ["'self'", "*.appspot.com*"]
```

I cannot seem to find clear documentation on how the wildcards work. Since Flask Talisman is from the Google Cloud Platform organization, I was hoping that I would be able to find more examples

Comment: Hey, I am having a similar issue, GAE is setting the CSP header for me (node), where and how can I overwrite it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying this:

```
'connect-src': ["'self'", 
                "http://review-dot-my-project.appspot.com", 
                "https://my-project.appspot.com"]
```

It looks like you don't need wild cards and you are better off with your CSP being as specific as possible.

You could also try this:

```
'connect-src': ["'self'", 
                "http://*.appspot.com", 
                "https://my-project.appspot.com"]
```

if you have other non-production versions of your app.

Comment: Where would one add these headers in a GAE project running on flex env?